# How can I save image onece in media folder in django when save in models in for loop?

Tags: django

this query save in models 4 times.
but i want to save image one time in media folder!

```
    img = 'mage_url'
    for i in [0,1,2,3]:
        cmp = CMP_MODEL(age=i,img=img,name='x')
        cmp.save()
```

Comment: Do you want to save one image at a time? Can you show more relevant code too?

Comment: i have problem.when i save  in models for field in [0,1,2,3],unfortunately,the image save in media for 4 times!!with these names :(g_4.jpg,g_4_bB13dFX.jpg,g_4_JxIEqt9.jpg,g_4_KV0EilO.jpg)

Comment: Is the Image you are trying to save repeated? Can you show previous code (from the one provided?)

Comment: yes it is reapeted!

Comment: Can you also show previous code?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#the-built-in-filesystem-storage-class

```
settings.py:

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

U can request the file via file input and then save the file

EDIT:
For the double Files Problems, u can check this very easy:

```
my_file = Path("/path/to/file")
if my_file.is_file():
# file exists
else:
# file is not here
```

So now u can Loop and if the file exists u can do whatevery u want and in the else part u can safe the file when its not there

Comment: what do u want to say?

Comment: i have problem.when i save in models for field in [0,1,2,3],unfortunately,the image save in media for 4 times!!with these names :(g_4.jpg,g_4_bB13dFX.jpg,g_4_JxIEqt9.jpg,g_4_KV0EilO.jpg)

Comment: i have one image that i want to save one time in media,because it  is same in for loop.

Comment: i can see above that the file is there for 4 times. u can remove the file after its there. ofc u can check if the file is there, make a if for that. when u try to remove the file use: os.remove("./media/urFile") and for check if the file is there: default_storage.exists("./media/urFile")

Comment: what is default_storage?

Comment: sorry, my bad! default_storage is wrong! from pathlib import Path

ill update my answer